# Can I use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) //(weak boom) and not get rejeted by apple?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unreal-engine4, haptic-feedback

I have this particular Problem: I am using UE4 to ship my iOS game. In my newest update I am trying to implement the taptic engine with objective-c Code. Now: I have tested my game with the official api for `Haptic Feedback` but it Always crashes my app. I tried it with

https://medium.com/@sdrzn/make-your-ios-app-feel-better-a-comprehensive-guide-over-taptic-engine-and-haptic-feedback-724dec425f10

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519); // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
```

and succeeded (iPhone 8). CAN I use it without being rejected or is it a private API?

Now, I have send the new Update to apple but got rejected because of this:

> Use of non public API MTLDebugDevice private API.

Now I have done some Research and it seemed that this hotfix may have solved it: https://forums.unrealengine.com/unreal-engine/announcements-and-releases/3303-current-available-quick-fix-solutions

I did run it and seemingly successfully patched UE4 shipping issue. But could I be rejected for using the method from above to trigger the haptic feedback?

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519); // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
```

Expect: get rejected by apple again and get banned from develper program.

Answer (score 2):

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` is not a private API so you can use it without any problem